# Right floated div element not show horizontally, break into new line

Tags: jquery, html, css

Dynamically added div element not show horizontally into a container div element which has a specific width value, always break into new line.

Here is my code

```js
var i=1;
$(document).ready(function () {
    
    $("#add").click(function(){
        
        $('#container').append(
          $('<div/>')
   .addClass("dDiv")
          .text("(hello world "+i+")")
        );
        i++;
    });
    
    
})
```

```css
#main{
 float:right;
 width:500px;
 border: 1px solid;
 overflow:hidden;
 white-space: nowrap;
 display: block;
}
.dDiv{ 
 display: inline-block;
 float:right;
 background-color:#ff0000;
 margin:2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div id="add">Add</div>
 <div id="chat" style="float:right">
   <div id="main">    
 <div id="container" style="float:right;">
    
 </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

[image]

Comment: I asked that yesterday, noone answered(

Comment: Sry I could not catch u.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1) remove `float:right`

2) set `direction:rtl` on the #main div

3) You *may* want to set `overflow:auto` to the #main div as well is order to see the additional dDivs

```js
var i = 1;
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#add").click(function() {

    $('#container').append(
      $('<div/>')
      .addClass("dDiv")
      .text("(hello world " + i + ")")
    );
    i++;
  });


})
```

```css
#main {
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: block;
  direction: rtl;
}
.dDiv {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="add">Add</div>
<div id="chat" style="float:right">
  <div id="main">
    <div id="container" style="float:right;">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the `float: right` declaration for `.dDiv`. The trick is that [all floated elements will automatically be declared as block level elements](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/). If you want to force no line break (therefore an overflow), you will have to treat them as inline or inline-block level elements.

To force `.dDiv` to honour its inline-block status, simply do not assign a float property to it.

```js
var i=1;
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#add").click(function(){
    $('#container').prepend(
      $('<div/>')
      .addClass("dDiv")
      .text("(hello world "+i+")")
    );
    i++;
  });
});
```

```css
#chat {
  float: right;
}
#main{
  width:500px;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#container {
  overflow:hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: right;
}
.dDiv{ 
  background-color:#ff0000;
  display: inline-block;
  margin:2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="add">Add</div>
<div id="chat">
  <div id="main">    
    <div id="container">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know but my requirement is                                     ===(hello world 3)(hello world 2)(hello world 1)==

Comment: @user1523291 Can you elabourate? I don't understand your requirement... perhaps a mockup of the desired behavior would be good.

Comment: run the code snippet,if u set float:left then it works fine, but not as my requirement, coz i want  (hello world 1) div element at the right position. If i set float to right i give me line break. Just run the code with float property right and left u will see the difference.

Comment: If you want to attach an image you should use a link and not inject it into my answer, because that is not what I've written.

Comment: Updated the code snippet. When it overflows, do you want the first element to be visible, or the most recently added one?

Comment: Yes i want first element visible.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the changes you need to make:

```
#main {
  text-align: right;
  direction: rtl;
  /* white-space: no-wrap; /* take this out */
}

.dDiv {
   /* float: right /* take this out */
}
```

Results:

```js
var i=1;
$(document).ready(function () {
    
    $("#add").click(function(){
        
        $('#container').append(
          $('<div/>')
   .addClass("dDiv")
          .text("(hello world "+i+")")
        );
        i++;
    });
    
    
})
```

```css
#main{
 float:right;
    direction:rtl;
    text-align: right;
 width:500px;
 border: 1px solid;
 overflow:hidden;
 display: block;
}
.dDiv{ 
 display: inline-block;
 background-color:#ff0000;
 margin:2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div id="add">Add</div>
 <div id="chat" style="float:right">
   <div id="main">    
 <div id="container" style="float:right;">
    
 </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: run the snippet you will see line break, and my requirement is (hello world4) (hello world3) (hello world2) (hello world1)